# Print Custom Label with new Dymo Connect SDK with VB.NET Windows Forms

Tags: vb.net, sdk, dymo

The following code will print a Label with default text & QR Code image from saved image path on computer, but I need to add replace the text & QR image with a custom text & QR Image. I cannot find any examples online of the new SDK, there is a little reference on the GitHub but cant piece anything together to work.

I Installed NuGet package Dynmo.Connect.SDK

```
Imports DymoSDK.Implementations

Dim dymoSDKLabel As DymoSDK.Implementations.DymoLabel

Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click

Dim SelectedPrinter As String = "DYMO LabelWriter 450"

Dim copies As Integer = 1

Dim barcodeGraphsQuality As Boolean = True

dymoSDKLabel = New DymoLabel()  
                         
dymoSDKLabel.LoadLabelFromFilePath("C:\Users\User\Documents\QR.dymo")

DymoPrinter.Instance.PrintLabel(dymoSDKLabel, SelectedPrinter, copies, barcodeGraphsQuality)

End Sub
```

Comment: The [DYMO Developer SDK Support Blog](https://developers.dymo.com/?wmp_theme_mode=desktop) says "DYMO.Connect.Framework [...] has the same functions of the old DYMO.Label.Framework," if that is any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wanted to say that I figured out the answer to my own problem in case someone is wondering how. I created a label in Dymo Connect software program called label.dymo. I added a TextObject and a ImageObject to the label, positioned in the middle and saved the label. I installed a Free NuGet package called QRCoder and referenced it in this sample code below. The String Variable called id is coming from my database and is the row id for what was just created(last insert row id). The QrCode generates a QRCode matching my id variable and then converts it to base64string because that what format the Dymo ImageObject supports. You can replace the id variable with any number or text as you need for your project.

```
Imports DymoSDK.Implementations

Imports QRCoder

Dim dymoSDKLabel As DymoSDK.Implementations.DymoLabel

Dim LabelTextObject As DymoSDK.Interfaces.ILabelObject

Dim LabelQRObject As DymoSDK.Interfaces.ILabelObject

Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click

Dim gen As New QRCodeGenerator

Dim data = gen.CreateQrCode(id, QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q)

Dim qrCode As New Base64QRCode(data)

Dim base64qrcode As String = qrCode.GetGraphic(20)

Dim SelectedPrinter As String = "DYMO LabelWriter 450"

Dim copies As Integer = 1

Dim barcodeGraphsQuality As Boolean = True

dymoSDKLabel = New DymoLabel()  
                         
dymoSDKLabel.LoadLabelFromFilePath("C:\Users\User\Documents\label.dymo")

LabelTextObject = dymoSDKLabel.GetLabelObject("TextObject")

dymoSDKLabel.UpdateLabelObject(LabelTextObject, id)

LabelQRObject = dymoSDKLabel.GetLabelObject("ImageObject")

dymoSDKLabel.UpdateLabelObject(LabelQRObject, base64qrcode)

DymoPrinter.Instance.PrintLabel(dymoSDKLabel, SelectedPrinter, copies, barcodeGraphsQuality)

End Sub
```